# EF core ,Create Custom Default Constraint Name

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, default-constraint

I am using EF core 2.1 and want to create custom default Constraint Name.

Currently, its getting create Constraint "DF__StudentBa__Admit__1DB06A4F"

Comment: Use HasConstraintName method on modelbuilder

Comment: I already tried but could succeed, it would be nice if you share some example to use?

Comment: is it working for you or not?

Comment: Sorry my bad, my mean was couldn't succeed ****

Comment: Sorry, I also misunderstood your question initially. It's not supported in EF Core as of now.

Answer (score 7):

Changing the Default constraint name is not supported in EF Core yet. You can track this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11502) for future reference.